# How to place/name an "intro" (not loader) before the index.html so the server reads it before?

Tags: html, server, host

How can I place/name an "intro" page before my index.html so the server reads it first?

That page is not a loader page, it simply has a video with a button for entering the website that Is connected to my homepage which is index.html 
(I also wouldn't want to be changing the location of my homepage at this point and turn the video into the index.html which seems to be one option.)

Do you guys have any tips? Thanks!

Comment: `turn the video into the index.html which seems to be one option` is the option

Comment: Yes, put the video in an overlay and slap it over your index.html

Comment: I would use HTML/CSS/JS on your current `index.html` for this. Make a container that covers the whole screen, and shows the video. Then when user clicks the enter button (or however you're doing it) the container hides.

Answer (score 0):

In an apache server environment create a .htaccess file and place the following code in it:
**`DirectoryIndex intro.html index.html index.php`**
Where intro.html is the first page you want to show.